# LDAP: creating a bind user with limited privileges

Tags: ldap, authentication, openldap

I need to bind to an OpenLDAP server to authenticate users, but I don't want this low-privileged or "delegated administrator" to be able to see more attributes than strictly necessary.

How do I reduce the attributes a bind user can see using a whitelist? 
What attributes are strictly necessary to authenticate users?

For example, there's no need for this specific bind user to see `NTPassword` and I suppose other attributes like home directory, etc.

This is what I did so far:

1. I have disabled anonymous bind:

   ```
   # disable anon bind
   dn: cn=config
   changetype: modify
   add: olcDisallows
   olcDisallows: bind_anon

   dn: cn=config
   changetype: modify
   add: olcRequires
   olcRequires: authc

   dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
   changetype: modify
   add: olcRequires
   olcRequires: authc
   ```
2. I've created an "Applications" OU and a "gitlab" user:

   ```
   # file: applications.ldif
   dn: ou=Applications,dc=example,dc=com
   objectclass: top 
   objectClass: organizationalunit
   ou: Applications

   dn: cn=gitlab,ou=Applications,dc=example,dc=com
   cn: gitlab
   objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
   objectClass: organizationalRole
   userPassword: {CRYPT}.....
   ```
3. To create the user, I've used the LDAP admin user:

   ```
   ldapadd -xvvv -f applications.ldif -D 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com' -W
   ```
4. To restrict the 'gitlab' privileges, I've tried this:

   ```
   # file: give-applications-access.ldif
   dn: cn=config
   changetype: modify
   # allow Applications (e.g. GitLab) access to userPassword
   access to dn.chidren="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" attrs=userPassword
     by dn.exact="ou=Applications,dc=eaxmple,dc=com" read
   ```
5. Then I've used `ldapmodify` to apply the previous LDIF:

   ```
   ldapmodify -xvvv  -D 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com' -W -f give-applications-access.ldif
   ```

Now **I can successfully authenticate users in `ou=People` from gitlab**. However, if I use e.g. `jxplorer` or `ldapsearch` with the `gitlab` user credentials, I can see all the user attributes *except* userPassword:

```
ldapsearch -h ldaps://ldap.example.com -p 636 -LLL -D 'cn=gitlab,ou=Applications,dc=example,dc=com' -s base -b "ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"  -s sub -W "(objectclass=*)" | grep -i userpassword | wc -l
0
```

What's going on here? I suppose gitlab is using `sambaNTPassword` to authenticate.. but I thought `attrs=userPassword` was read only, and now it's not even in the attributes.

Apologies for pasting all the commands - I'm leaving them here in the hope that others will find this useful. Most of the documentation I've found describes every single option available but doesn't give any good examples that are usable on recent versions of OpenLDAP; and most of the examples available concern editing slapd.conf and not the "new" database (cn=config) type, so it's hard to understand what's relevant.

UPDATE - the current ACL is:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by * read
```

I've followed [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159796) to read the ACLs which in my case were on `{0}mdb`: `ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config 'olcDatabase={1}mdb'`

Comment: Please include your full current ACL.

Comment: @84104 I've updated my question with the ACLs. It's at the end

Comment: I have a feeling from reading your ACLs that the only two attributes that are restricted ar the `userPassword` and `shadowLastChange`. Rule `{2}` clearly states that everything else is readable by anyone else... if I am not mistaken